# Can't get onSingleTapConfirmed from Fresco Drawee in Android

Tags: android, fresco

In my app I use GestureDetector on Fresco to get onSingleTapConfirmed. But its not called. In logs I only get `onTouch`. This is code from my Fragment that is populating my ViewPager.

```
DraweeView draweeImageView = (DraweeView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.drawee_view);

        final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(App.getContext(), new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
                ((MediaViewActivity) getActivity()).onSingleTapConfirmed();
                Log.d(TAG, "onSingleTapConfirmed");
                return super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e);
            }
        });

            DraweeController controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
                    .setImageRequest(ImageRequest.fromUri(ThumbUrl)
                    .build();

            draweeImageView.setController(controller);

        draweeImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onTouch");
                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved my issue by overriding `onDown` with returning `true` in GestureDetector.

```
final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(App.getContext(), new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
                ((MediaViewActivity) getActivity()).onSingleTapConfirmed();
                return super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }
        });
```